# Show that the vector field $\operatorname{grad}f$ is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $ f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Define a vector field $\operatorname{grad}f$ in $M$ as
$$\langle\operatorname{grad}f,\,V\rangle=df(V)$$
for all vector field $V$ in $M$. I have to show that $\operatorname{grad}f$ is smooth.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: One idea: Restrict to coordinate charts, and show that the components of grad f are smooth functions.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain some more?

Comment: Let $V=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ for some coordinate $x_i.$ Then compute $\langle \text{grad} f, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\rangle$ and see what you get. If you get a smooth function then $\text{grad} f$ will be smooth.

Comment: Alternatively, you could more generally prove that the metric dual $W\leftrightarrow \langle W, \cdot\rangle$ is an isomorphism between smooth vector fields and smooth one-forms. (It would be the same proof as Alex Zorn/mck suggest, but more general.)

Comment: Ok, if someone wwants to write an answer that would be just excellent, i get the idea, gut i need the formalism

Answer (score 1):

Here's one slightly different method from the one I suggested in my comment: Let $U$ be an open subset of $M$ on which there exists an orthonormal frame $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. That is, the $e_i$ are smooth vector fields satisfying $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$. (You can always find such vector fields on a set admitting a coordinate chart by using Gram-Schmidt).

Now, it should be straightforward to show that:

$$\text{grad } f = \sum_{i=1}^n df(e_i)\cdot e_i$$
In other words, $\text{grad } f$ can be written as a sum of smooth functions times smooth vector fields. And so it must be smooth.